# Babel- How to make the 'exclude' from "Config Merging options" to work?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, transpiler

I'm trying to make the 'exclude' option of the "Config Merging options" to work without success (although using 'test' or 'include' options work).
I tried in both babel.config.json and babelrc.json files.
In babelrc in these ways:

```
   {
"overrides": [{
        "exclude": ["/\\.js$/"],
       "plugins":["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
        }]     
  }
```

another:

```
{
    "exclude": ["/\\.js$/"],
     "overrides": [{
       "plugins":["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
        }]  
  }
```

another 2:

```
{ 
     "overrides": [{
        "exclude": ["./codefile.js"],

       "plugins":["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
        }]  
  }
```

another 3:

```
{ 
     "overrides": [{
        "exclude": ["codefile.js"],

       "plugins":["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
        }]  
  }
```

The command is:

```
"babel subPackage --out-dir subPackage-lib"
```

In babel.config in this way:

```
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
    "exclude": ["./index.js"]

}
```

The command is:

```
babel index.js --out-dir compiled_indexDir
```

Nothing seems to work.

The versions are:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.14.3",
  "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
```

Will appreciate your help.
THANKS

Comment: You are passing a string, not an regular expression literal. Try `"exclude": [/\.js$/],`

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling, but it is inside of a json file so it can't be used like this.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the file structure you have and what are you trying to compile? Your example command for instance only compiles `index.js` anyway, so what's the point of excluding? Also if you want a regex, you can always rename the file to be `.js`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, is was simplified for a question purposes.
There is the root of the project with babel.config.json, and a subPackage with babelrc.json.
In the subPackage folder i have two JS files and none of them seems to NOT tranpile after inserting it in "exclude".
And your answer about regex is not clear. Not the regex nor the string path works.